# Выезжающая панель в android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Доброго времени суток! Я реализовал в своем приложении нижнюю панель с кнопками которая появляется при нажатии на некую кнопку. Она появляется мгновенно а я бы хотел чтобы она плавно выезжала снизу вверх. Можно ли это сделать и если да то как?

Answer (score 2):

Пример анимации смещение по вертикали для `View`

```
    ViewCompat.animate(card).alpha(1).yBy(2 * cardHeight).withStartAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ViewCompat.setElevation(card, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation));
        }
    }).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ViewCompat.setElevation(profileTypeCard, card.getCardElevation());
        }
    }).start();
```